# how to validate cityname,pincode from one string?

Tags: android

Example: I have a EditText and I want to check the first word is the city name and second word  is the pincode. These both words are separated by comma(,).

Comment: Just use `String.split(",")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey try this if you don't want to use split. YOu need to get string into a variable from edittext and then use the following code for doing yourself able to validate :)

```
String str = "tim,52250";
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str, ",");
while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
 System.out.println(st.nextToken());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this way..

```
String content="Mehsana,384001";
String[] contentArray=content.split(",");
```

And you will get

```
contentArray[0]=Mehsana
contentArray[1]=384001
```

then you can validate each string content..

Answer (score 0):

Use split() to get the things done.

Ex:

```
String s= "abc,123"
String s1[]=s.split(",");

String city=s1[0];
String pincode=s1[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String strInput = editText.getText().toString();
        String strSplit [] = strInput.split(",");
        System.out.println("CityName : " + strSplit[0]);
        System.out.println("PinCode : " + strSplit[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String  data = "ali,524513"
String  []array   = data.split(",")

you can validate array[0] and array[1] :)
System.out.println("Name: "+array[0]+" code: "+array[1]);
```